# ng-pattern to ensure that a textfield letter does not end with a specific word

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

with this code snippet I am trying to ensure that a textfield does not end with any of the letters outline in the $scope.pointPattern

```
$scope.pointPattern = /^(?!.*ess|ence|sports|riding?$)/;
            $scope.error = "not valid";
```

on running the code, only when the field ends with **ess** that the error is shown but other letters are never blacklisted

```
e.g 
football ess > shows error not valid
footbal ence > does not show error and likewise on sports and riding
```

what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^(?!.*ess|ence|sports|riding?$)` regex matches a string that does not end with `ess` and that does not start with `ence`, `sports`, and does not end with `riding` and `ridin`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EIFHJs/2). That happens because the alternatives are not *grouped* and the `$` only

You need to group these alternatives.

Use

```
$scope.pointPattern = /^(?!.*(?:ess|ence|sports|riding?)$)/;
                             ^^^   ^    ^      ^       ^
```

The `(?!` and the last `)` define the boundaries of the negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and the `(?:ess|ence|sports|riding?)` is a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches any of the alternatives listed inside it delimited with `|` ([*alternation operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)).

Comment: Had to group it using your solution and this worked for me $scope.pointPattern = /^(?!.*ess|.*ence|.*sports|.*riding?$)/; as well

Comment: @user10445503 Note it matches strings that do not contain `ess`, `ence`, `sports` and that do not end with `riding` or `ridin`. The `$` only refers to `.*riding?` alternative, other branches do not "see" the `$` anchor.

Comment: You are the regex king